# If the electric field is the gradient of the potential, then can we say that whenever potential is zero, the electric field is zero?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, differentiation

For example, in a dipole, at the center of the two charges making up the dipole, the potential is zero but the electric field is non-zero. But if $E = -\operatorname{grad}V$, then why is $E$ not zero?

Another example: In the case of two positive charges, the electric field is zero at the mid-point of line joining them, but potential is non-zero.
What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Because you are not linking the _gradient_ with the change (slope in 1-D) of the function. Just because the function is zero does not imply that the slope is (and vice-versa). The potential of a dipole is non-zero away from the center of the dipole, so there must be a gradient.

Comment: you are not understanding what a gradient (or more basic, a derivative) is.

Answer (score 7):

Here are the two arrangements of charges that you have mentioned shown as potential, $V$, against position along line joining charges, $x$, graphs - the one dimensional case $E_{\rm x} = - \frac{dV}{dx}$

[image]

If you added $20$ to all the potential values does that change the shape of the graphs?
The answer is "No" and this then means that the gradients of the graphs at positions $A$ and $B$ do not change.

When you find the gradient the important parameter is the difference between the potentials and so it does not matter if you have $[3-5]$ or $[(3+20) -(5+20)]$ the result is still $-2$.

As expected at position $A$ the gradient (= - electric field) is zero and the potential can be any value you choose it to be and at position $B$ the gradient (= - electric field) is negative which shows the electric field to be positive ie in the positive x-direction towards the negative charge.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the fact that $\vec E = -\nabla V$ implies E is the gradient of the scalar field V. Just as in a normal function like say $y = sin(x)$ , at $x = \pi$ , y = 0, but is $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $x = \pi$ zero? Obviously, basic mathematics tells you that the answer is no. So, it is not necessary that the derivative must vanish wherever the function vanishes. So $\vec E$ need not be zero wherever $V$ is zero.  Similarly, you can convince yourself, that a function whose derivative vanishes at $x = a$(suppose) need not have a root at $x = a$. So, V need not be zero when its gradient ($\vec E$) is zero. Read up on basic vector calculus from Griffiths or even online.

Answer (score 0):

No, the electrostatic field is not zero where the potential is zero. The electric field is the negative gradient of the potential as you state. The gradient of the potential is, however, in general not zero where the zero of the potential happens to be.